# Showing a UIWebView modally on top of whole application through UIWindow from class inherited from NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, modal-dialog, uiwindow

I have a class which works with social networks related stuff. At some point it may want to put up a UIWebView modally. It may not know which view controller is working at the moment. May I show WebView through UIWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController 
  presentModalViewController:yourVC animated:YES]
```

[UIApplication keyWindow Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW32):

> **keyWindow**
>
> The application's key window. (read-only)
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property holds the UIWindow object in the windows array that is
>   most recently sent the makeKeyAndVisible message.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

[UIWindow rootViewController Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW33):

> **rootViewController**
>
> The root view controller for the window.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The root view controller provides the content view of the window.
>   Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window. If the window has an existing view
>   hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are
>   installed.
>
> The default value of this property is nil.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Comment: [UIApplication keyWindow] creates a error, saying there is no such property as keyWindow on object UIApplication?

Comment: Oh, it's [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow! Thanks

Comment: @IlyaLapan Opps.  Forgot to add the singleton accessor for UIApplication like you pointed out.  I updated my answer.  Glad I could help.